# Dealing with infinite singularities in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, infinity

I have been graphing the graph for 1/r or 1/sqrt(x^2 + y^2) in Python recently. When (x,y) -> (0,0), 1/r goes to inf. To deal with this, I used np.nan_to_num to deal with the infinities but it just gives an error. I just wanna make my graph look nice and not have these diamond things like in this picture:

[image: picture]

Here is my code:

```
min, max, ds = -10, 10, 0.5
x = np.arange(min, max, ds)
y = np.arange(min, max, ds)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

def potential(X, Y, X0, Y0):
    return 1/np.sqrt((X-X0)**2 + (Y-Y0)**2)

plt.figure(figsize = (9.5,8))
plt.contourf(X, Y, potential(X, Y, 0, 0), 100)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("Electric potential", fontsize = 20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a bit of a cheap trick, but: can't you just use a step size `ds` that does not does not visit `0`?. For example `ds = 0.49` or `ds = 0.51`?

Comment: The graph looks good (well, the centers do) but it doesn't really look right. The right one should look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/ldwmXg2.png) but without the ugly center. However, if I use ds = 0.49 or 0.51, I get something that looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/8zUiWF3.png), and it doesn't get any better when I try to approach 0.5 from the left or the right. What other things should I try?

Comment: The question says plotting $1/r$, but the code is plotting something more complicated, probably the gradient of $1/r_1 - 1/r_2$, where the distances are calculated from different origins.  That makes it hard to understand.  Can you post a minimum, reproducible example?

Comment: Sure, I'll add a simpler version on the post.